# Video download using Alamofire is freezing the UI in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alamofire, background-process

I am developing a Video editing Application in Swift. I am downloading video clips with Progress.

My problem is when I am downloading the video using Alamofire then this freezes my UI until the process will get complete. Here is my code:

```
    //MARK: -  Download Video file
    func downloadVideoFileFromUrl(videoUrl: URL, video: VideoFileModel) {

        var uniqueVideoID = ""
        var uniqueID = ""

        uniqueID = video.fileID

        uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + ".MOV"

        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

            // the name of the file here I kept is yourFileName with appended extension
            documentsURL.appendPathComponent(uniqueVideoID)
            return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
        }

        var vidProgress: Float = 0.0


        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 900
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 900

        manager.download(videoUrl, to:destination)
            .downloadProgress { (progress) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    vidProgress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
                    video.downloadFromUrlProgress = vidProgress

                    //post notification
                    let userInfo = [ "videoFileModel" : video]
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "VideoDownloadProgress"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)

                })

            }
            .response { defaultDownloadResponse in

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    print(defaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL as Any)

                    if defaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL != nil{
                        video.localFilePath = (defaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL?.absoluteString)!
                        video.downloadFromUrlProgress = 1
                        video.isVideoDownload = true

                        let userInfo = [ "videoFileModel" : video]
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "VideoDownloadProgress"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
                        print("Completed!")

                    }

                })
        }
    }
```

I am calling this method using

`DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync {  }`

Can anyone help me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you try other qos values like background ?. and  keep note that Alamofire.SessionManager.default is shared instance so  for now every request has 900 time out

Comment: Yes I tried. Thanks for your note. Can you help me to tell max value of timeoutIntervalForRequest?

Comment: No there is no standard benchmark for timeout values what you can do is  You can keep separate session for download / upload task so it won't be conflicted with normal requests

Comment: use async task you are using sync

Comment: Okay but still it's freezing the UI.

Comment: What happens if call the function without DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync { }?

Comment: Try one thing comment everything inside progress block and use async  also instead of sync may be issue with `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification...` line

Comment: @PrashantTukadiyaLet me check with this, I will update you.

Comment: When I have commented everything inside progress block, then UI is not freezing @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: You need to make the network request in the background thread. DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {  ...<Your request>...  }
Only use the main thread for updating views(UI works).

Comment: What you are doing is continuously  firing the notification using this line `                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "VideoDownloadProgress"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
` You can use trailing closure in your method and call closure when progress block executes with value. Hope you understand what I am trying to say

Comment: Yes @PrashantTukadiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code:

```
func download(url: String,fileName: String,progressUpdate: ((_ percent: Double) -> Void)? = nil, completion:@escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?,_ fileUrl: URL?) -> Void) {
        let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
        Alamofire.download(url)
            .downloadProgress(queue: utilityQueue) { progress in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    progressUpdate?(progress.fractionCompleted)
                }
            }
            .responseData { response in
                if let data = response.result.value {
                    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    do {
                        try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                        completion(true,nil,fileURL)
                    } catch {
                        completion(false,error,nil)
                    }
                }
        }

    }
```

How to use it:

```
download(url: "", fileName: "filName", progressUpdate: { (progress) in
            print("Progress \(progress)")
        }) { (success, error, filePath) in
            print("success \(success) error \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "nil") path \(filePath?.absoluteString ?? "nil")")
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am facing issue with NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification...

Comment: @AnandGautam the above code avoids the use of Notifications. Look at the usage, you are getting the progress where you are calling the download function. the above code can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: My downloadVideoFileFromUrl method is written into View Modal class, so to update the downloading progress I am using NotificationCenter.

Comment: Okay @Sahil Let me test with your code. I will update you.

Comment: @AnandGautam can you provide a sample project which can reproduces the same error?

Comment: I have to download back to back 8 video clips, but its getting stop after 6th Video clip. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @AnandGautam there can be a number of reasons. Is it printing any error or getting failed?

Comment: Can I set 12000 for timeoutIntervalForRequest value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195850/discussion-between-sahil-manchanda-and-anand-gautam).

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync { }
```

try

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { }
```

Looks like you are trying to download video as synchronized operation

Comment: I already tried changing this, but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to check the progress delta, if the progress changes less than 1%, just return and ignore it instead of call dispatch.async

Comment: How can I check for this?

Comment: if new_progress - old_progress < 0.01 then
    return;

old_progress = new_progress

Comment: I don't have reference of old_progress value, is it possible to get 'progress.fractionCompleted' value like 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4.....0.8, 0.9, 1.0 So only ten times I will call 'NotificationCenter' method instead of multiple time?

Comment: it's better to add one, as the progress may never be 0.1 (e.g. first 0.09, second 0.11). BTW, i think `vidProgress` is the old value you want.